# Sort without altering cell index

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am looking for a solution to following issue :

I want to know the sum of A/Cs 3, 4 and 5 all the time in H7 (In Picture).
But, I will also want to sort the date occasionally to verify the next due but without affecting H7

[image: Before sort]

But, What actually happens when sorting in ascending order, the Cell index itself is getting changed and the value at H7 gives me the different value (which is not what I want).

[image: After Sort]

Is it possible to freeze the Cell index during sort?

Comment: The Image is an example only. I wanted to give an example to explain my problem easily... In my actual sheet the account number will have several digits and wont be in any order and hence I cant filter A/C with a range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) with OR criteria.

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A:A, {3,4,5}, B:B ))
```

Comment: Thanks. But, A/C 3,4 and 5 are just examples. In my actual sheet it will have several digits and wont be in any order

Comment: Unlike the **>=** and **<=** solution, these do not have to be ordered. Just wrapped in math braces; e.g. **{** and **}** and separated by commas. If this is still inadequate, I humbly suggest that you edit your question to accurately reflect what you are looking for instead of making up examples that have nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: This solution seem to be working in MS Excel but the same is not working in Google sheets... It just takes the first entry in google sheets. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @giboo - Try `=sum(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(A:A, {3,4,5},B:B )))` on google-sheets.

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula to calculate total:
`=SUMIFS(B4:B8,A4:A8,">=3",A4:A8,"<=5")`

What this does is it adds the values in the range `B4:B8` only when values in range `A4:A8` is greater than or equal to 3 and less than or equal to 5.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But the Image is an example only. I wanted to give an example to explain my problem easily... In my actual sheet I will have several digits and wont be in any order and hence I cant filter similar to >=3 and <=5. And, thats why I thought freezing the cell to the account number would be one of my solutions...