# Using sum if with two different arguments

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have a spread sheet that has columns like so:

```
Column A -- Column B -- Column C -- Column d -- Column E
1001          5.00        D           1001        10.00
1001          3.00        D           1002        10.00
1001          2.00        N
1002          5.00        D
1002          5.00        D
```

I've been using the =SUMIF formula to sum the values into column E, it looks something like:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5,D1,B1:B5)
```

From what I understand it looks for the value of D1, finds every match in the range of A1:A5 and adds together the values that correspond from Column B.

My issues is that the value in column C can differ from D or N, I would like to add two additional columns, one that summarizes all instances of 1001 with the value of D in column C, and one that summarizes all instances of 1001 with the value of N in column C.

I have tried using the  =SUMIFS() formula, but excel throws the error that I do not have enough arguments. I wrote the formula like so:

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A5, D1, C1:C5 = "D", B1:B5)
```

That's when I was returned with "Not enough valid arguments.." Most of what I have found requires the use of more than 2 arguments. Most recently I have tried using the examples provided [Here](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-sumifs-sum-cells-match-multiple-criteria-excel#sthash.pD3BRSFJ.dpbs).

Comment: `=SUMIFS( B1:B5,A1:A5, D1, C1:C5, "D")`

Comment: See [HERE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) for more info and a little video.

Comment: Would that be reversing my math, by checking for column B for D and adding column A if Column C is equal to D?

Comment: No the SUMIFS() has a different order than SUMIF().  `=SUMIFS(RangeToSum, 1stCriteriaRange, 1stCriteria, 2ndCriteriaRange, 2ndCriteria ...)`

Comment: Yes this worked beautifully! If you can post it as an answer, I will select yours!

Comment: Mark @teylyn as correct.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for Sumif() and Sumifs() is slightly different. Keep in mind that neither function uses the = sign for the comparison.

Sumif syntax: `=SUMIF(range, condition, [sum range])`

Sumifs syntax: `=SUMIFS(sum range, criteria range1, criteria1, criteria range2, criteria2,...)`

So change your formula

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A5, D1, C1:C5 = "D", B1:B5)
```

to

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B5, A1:A5, D1, C1:C5,"D")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a different syntax between the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) and [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B).

The reason for this is due to the fact that SUMIF can use the *sum_range* as its *criteria_range*. From your example, if you just wanted to sum numbers in column B that were *greater than 4* a SUMIF could be written two ways.

```
'SUMIF(criteria_and_sum_range, criteria)
=sumif(B:B, "<"&4)
'SUMIF(criteria_range, criteria, [sum_range])
=sumif(B:B, "<"&4, B:B)
```

The SUMIF only has a single optional parameter. If that is missing then the first parameter (*criteria_range*) is also used as the *sum_range*. If it includes its optional parameter, then the first is used for criteria and the latter is used for the sum.

But a SUMIFS by its nature can only perform the latter and the *sum_range* comes first because there could be more than 1 *criteria_range* / *criteria* pairs.

```
'SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)
=sumifs(B:B, B:B, "<"&4)
```

Since the numbers of *criteria_range* / *criteria* pairs in a SUMIFS could conceivable be 1, 2 many more, a tighter structure with the non-optional *sum_range* as the first parameter is necessary.

Comment: Is "<"&4" act like a regular expression of some sorts? or is that just saying check for less than 4? I don't understand the quotes and ampersand

Comment: It can be either `"<"&4` or `"<4"` ; they are both the same thing. I had inadvertently added an extra quote.

Comment: Would there be a way to use or? I tried adding a different range something like   =SUMIFS( "original args", E1:E5, OR("V","A")) Then I also tried = SUMIFS("Orginial args", E1:E5, <>0)) Both of which return errors f #VALUE!

Comment: Accidentally posted the comment without any information, my bad

Comment: Yes, but that would be another question. Essentially, you need to wrap SUM() around the sumif(s) like =sum(sumifs(..., ....)). Post a new question if you run into trouble or take a look at [Sort without altering cell index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348432/sort-without-altering-cell-index/32348613#32348613).